# Resolving URL based on Requesting Namespace

Tags: django, namespaces, django-urls, django-cms

I am building a website using DjangoCMS that has about 10 instances of the same app. These different instances will just be used to serve different files on different pages.

Everything is working except when I go to a different instance of the application and go to the detail view it reverts back to the original application's URL and namespace.

For example, going to `/university/term-syncc/` and clicking on an item in the list view redirects me to `/marketing/4/` or whatever the ID is of that item.

If I go to `/university/term-syncc/4/`it works but I cannot get that URL to resolve automatically. I know it has something to do with my `get_absolute_url` calling the `assets` namespace but how can I force it to check the current app namespace and then run a reverse from there?

models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("assets:asset_detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

HTML

```
<li>
    <a href="{{obj.get_absolute_url}}">{{ obj.name }} test</a>
</li>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', asset_list_view, name="asset_list"),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', asset_detail_view, name='asset_detail'),
```

Comment: did you try to do it with the django Detail view ?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by this

Comment: @ChrisWendel Have you namespaced all of your apps? In urls.py files of each?

Comment: Is it necessary to create a new urls.py file for each instance of an app? Where would I put each of these url files?

Comment: @ChrisWendel You would put urls.py in each app and than include all of them in project's urls.py. If you design your project this way, you will be able to give each urls.yp file its own namespace and than call urls from different apps unambiguously throughout the project.

Comment: problem is I am using DjangoCMS all of these apps are just instances of the same app. I have about 10 instances of the same app, university, marketing, advertising, pricing, etc. All of these app instances do the same thing but I want them to resolve to their own path rather than to the `/marketing/` path. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this is to provide a configuration model for your application. Then it can use that config per instance.

```
pip install aldryn-apphooks-config
```

First off, the docs are here; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/namespaced_apphooks.html#aldryn-apphooks-config

By implementing this solution your method becomes something like this;

```
class Asset(models.Model):

    app_config = AppHookConfigField(
        AssetConfig,
        verbose_name=_('Config'),
        help_text='',
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url for this object."""
        if self.app_config and self.app_config.namespace:
            namespace = '{0}:'.format(self.app_config.namespace)
        else:
            namespace = ''

        return reverse(
            '{0}assets:asset_detail'.format(namespace),
            kwargs={"id": self.id}
        )
```

Without installing this app, you can still namespace your app hooks, with that `Application instance name` field on the page advanced settings. You could use this instead, but it'd need args/kwargs passing around.

In your view or templates, you could do `request.current_page.application_namespace` to get the namespace from the page so you could use that for your links.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I had given up on this!

Comment: @ChrisWendel Never give up! If you're ever unsure on how to do something with CMS take a look at what the developer of CMS does with their packages on github; https://github.com/aldryn/ or https://github.com/divio/